# Google Storage signedUploadUrl, fetching upload url returns: Bad content type. Please use multipart

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, php-7, google-cloud-php-client

I want to let my user upload large files directly to Google Storage. According to [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/storageobject?method=signedUploadUrl) I should be able to use the PHP SDK to generate a signed upload url. I do so like this:

```
$storage = new StorageClient(['keyFilePath' =>  $myKeyPath ]);

$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketname);
$object = $bucket->object($relativepath);

$sessionURI = $object->signedUploadUrl(
    # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
    new \DateTime('15 min'),
    [
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'contentType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'version' => 'v4',
    ]
);
```

The documentation says I need to `POST` to the returned `$sessionURI` in order to then get the ACTUAL url I can upload to. The docs:

> ## signedUploadUrl
>
> Create a Signed Upload URL for this object.
>
> ...
>
> In order to upload data, a session URI must be obtained by sending an
>   HTTP POST request to the URL returned from this method.

However, when I try to `POST` to the `$sessionURI`, I get the error:

`POST object expects Content-Type multipart/form-data`

So, I explicitly set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` and then I get the error:

`Bad content type.  Please use multipart.`

I've tried doing this from code as well as using curl on the command line, and I've tried setting the `Content-Type` but nothing seems to work (I added some new lines to make this readable, but it's all one line originally):

```
/usr/bin/curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-id.appspot.com/uploads/uploadfilename.jpg?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount
@mydomain.com&Expires=1591657512&Signature=veryverylongsignatureasdfasdfasdfasdfadfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

I've tried a bunch of different examples and I've tried just following exactly what the documentation says and nothing seems to work.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

---- UPDATE

I tried to go back to the beginning with Google's sample code, which still didn't work. This was the curl command that Google's sample code was giving me:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --upload-file /path/to/file.jpg 
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-id.appspot.com/uploads/uploadfilename.jpg?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount
@mydomain.com&Expires=1591657512&Signature=veryverylongsignatureasdfasdfasdfasdfadfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

That was giving me:

`Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to start a resumable upload. A request to begin a resumable upload is a POST request. Your PHP code is signing a request to do a PUT request.

Comment: You must use the same HTTP method specified when signing in the actual request. In your case, you should use the PUT method. For `curl` use the `-T` option. You mention "large files". Anything larger than a few hundred megabytes will probably result in a bad user experience.

Comment: @JohnHanley The PUT is what the final upload request is supposed to be, but I'm still at the intermediate step of trying to get the uri that I can PUT to, and that request needs to be a POST according to the documentation. This upload will be happening in the background of an iOS app, the user experience will be just fine.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough The PUT is what the final upload request is supposed to be, but I'm still at the intermediate step of trying to get the uri that I can PUT to, and that request needs to be a POST according to the documentation.

Comment: The point of my comment is that the method specified in the signing must match the request method. Next, do you want file upload or `resumable` file upload? In the first case, use PUT, in the second case use POST. `curl` supports the first method. Refer to this link for the uploadTpe: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm ok with resumable or non-resumable, doesn't matter to me. The reason I'm trying this path is because the max file upload size for Google App Engine is like 20-32 MB (something like that), but I need users to be able to upload larger files from our iOS app. And I don't want to build credentials into the app to allow the app to upload files directly, so that someone can't steal the credentials. So, I figured this signedUploadUrl() would do the trick, because I could have my web app securely generate the upload url that is only valid for X minutes, then the app could upload.

Comment: The followup PUT requests after the POST do not need to be separately signed. Only the initial POST needs a signature.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I wasn't attempting to sign the follow-up PUT requests, I was just trying to PUT the data to the url exactly was it was returned by the signing code. I ended up figuring out how to do everything with signedUrl() instead of signedUploadUrl()... a pair of really badly named functions, since both of them allow uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally tried the sample code that google provided and it didn't work (which was the two-step signedUrl() method, which just requires one api call and one PUT call), so I went through many iterations trying different functions and different methods, following different examples on the web, all of which kept failing (including the three-step signedUploadUrl() method which requires an api call, a POST, and then another POST (or maybe PUT)).

I still need to figure out how to get this working within my app, but I at least got it working with curl which is a proof of concept on the permissions and api calls.

The reason my original curl tests were failing was because the upload url contained standard query params which include `&` and those were screwing up the command when I ran the curl command via `system()`.

So, back to the original curl PUT request with the simple `signedUrl()` approach, the bad command looked like this:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --upload-file /path/to/file.jpg 
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-id.appspot.com/uploads/uploadfilename.jpg?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount
@mydomain.com&Expires=1591657512&Signature=veryverylongsignatureasdfasdfasdfasdfadfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

while the working command included quotes around the URL to avoid the shell grabbing and interpreting the `&`s:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --upload-file /path/to/file.jpg 
"https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-id.appspot.com/uploads/uploadfilename.jpg?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount
@mydomain.com&Expires=1591657512&Signature=veryverylongsignatureasdfasdfasdfasdfadfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inviting users to upload files via HTML forms, you'll want to use [`Bucket::generatedSignedPostPolicyV4`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/latest/storage/bucket?method=generateSignedPostPolicyV4).

That method will return an array containing an action URI (for your `<form action>` property) and a list of fields which you need to include in the form. Iterate over those and embed them as key/value fields using hidden inputs.

The formatting for the sample on the link above seems to be a bit messed up, but you can see a complete (if simplified) sample in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/v0.133.1/Storage/src/Bucket.php#L1484-L1505).

Comment: I'm trying to generate the upload url which is passed down to an iOS app so that the iOS app can upload the files in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the endpoint you are POSTing to does not accept form multipart data. Try setting your Content-Type to "multipart/related" instead of "multipart/form-data" and see if you are able to proceed. Check this link [Cloud Storage Upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload) for more help.

Comment: I get the same response. `Bad content type.  Please use multipart.`

Comment: I'm uploading a large file and post it with a form values. Nothing seems work. (with PHP 5 createUploadUrl worked perfectly)